# Screenshot PowerShell while remote server is minimized

Tags: powershell, screenshot

I'm currently using the `PowerShellscript` below to take a screenshot of a file and save it to a local drive. This works fine on my desktop when the excel file is open. However, I'm trying to take the screenshot on a remote server that I have minimized, as I'm running this script there overnight. When the screenshot gets saved to the local drive on the remote server, it's just blank. IF I have the remote server screen open, it works fine. I'm looking for assistance to see if this is even possible. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
$app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

$app.windowstate= "xlMaximized"

$app.Visible = $True

$app.displayAlerts = $False

$wb = $app.Workbooks.Open("C:\TakeAScreenshotPlease.xlsm")

$wb.Name

$wb.RefreshAll()

Start-Sleep -s 460

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

function screenshot([Drawing.Rectangle]$bounds, $path) {

$bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height

$graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

$graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)

$bmp.Save($path)

$graphics.Dispose()

$bmp.Dispose()
}


$bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 271, 1541, 950) 
screenshot $bounds "C:\TakeAScreenshotPlease\FakeFolder.png"
```

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to take a screen shot from a minimized application, but it will probably work if you move the window off screen by setting it's X and Y coordinates outside your display's viewable area. Are you logged in when it's executing? If your screen is locked it will not be possible to take a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks - not sure what you mean by 'move the window off screen by setting it's X and Y coordinates outside your display's viewable area'? As far as logged in, my virtual machine is never shut off. meaning i run all my executables there... but as far as have the screen up and visible and 'logged in' no... however, the virtual machine is set with only my credentials

Comment: I meant that you could move the Excel window off of your VM's screen instead of minimizing - put the top left corner on pixel 1921 if your screen is 1920 pixels wide. But `CopyFromScreen` probably requires a visible screen to copy from. If your session is locked or signed out of Windows, it can't get a handle to the visible screen.